# Self hosted BlazeMeter Sense and Yandex Overload analogues

Tags: load-testing, blazemeter, yandex-tank

Are there any self-hosted load testing results services like Yandex Overload and BlazeMeter Sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any but starting from [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) it is possible to [generate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) during the test or afterwards.

Another option is using [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/) to plot various charts in .png format

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to [Analyze Jmeter Results](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/19/how-to-analyze-jmeter-results/) without those hosted result services:

- **UI Listeners**: good for light load tests with a single load generator,
- **JTL Files**: analyze them using the XSL provided within `JMETER_HOME/extras`,
- [Backend Listener + InfluxDB + Grafana](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/19/how-to-analyze-jmeter-results/#backend-listener): self hosted solution based on 2 other open source components (InfluxDB and Grafana).

Sadly, Blazemeter Sense (previously **Loadosophia**) used to be free (or at least cheap enough), until Blazemeter bought it end of 2014.